# Issue in must and should in Query for ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to have "must" and "should" both in my bool but not getting the desired result.

For the below query I am having 3 and 1 documents respectively.

```
{
    "timeout":"5s",
    "query":{
    "bool":{
    "must":[
        {"term":{"rgtnRelt.reltRcptIdI":{"value":"9175","boost":1.0}}},
        {"term":{"rgtnRelt.reltRcptIdI":{"value":"9844","boost":1.0}}},
        {"term":{"rgtnRelt.reltRcptIdI":{"value":"0075","boost":1.0}}},
        {"term":{"rgtnRelt.reltRcptIdI":{"value":"7678","boost":1.0}}}
        ],
    "adjust_pure_negative":true,"boost":1.0
        }
        }
}





{
    "timeout":"5s",
    "query":{
    "bool":{
    "must":[
        {"term":{"_id":{"value":"9175-9844-0075-7678","boost":1.0}}}
        ],
    "adjust_pure_negative":true,"boost":1.0
        }
        }
}
```

To get all the document in a single query I have written like the below but still getting the 3 documents only.

```
{
    "timeout":"5s",
    "query":{
    "bool":{
    "must":[
        {"term":{"rgtnRelt.reltRcptIdI":{"value":"9175","boost":1.0}}},
        {"term":{"rgtnRelt.reltRcptIdI":{"value":"9844","boost":1.0}}},
        {"term":{"rgtnRelt.reltRcptIdI":{"value":"0075","boost":1.0}}},
        {"term":{"rgtnRelt.reltRcptIdI":{"value":"7678","boost":1.0}}}
        ],
    "should":[
        {"term":{"_id":{"value":"9175-9844-0075-7678"}}}
        ],
    "adjust_pure_negative":true,"boost":1.0
        }
        }
}
```

I just want the all the documents using single query

Answer (score 0):

Try like this instead:

```
{
  "timeout": "5s",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "rgtnRelt.reltRcptIdI": [
              "9175",
              "9844",
              "0075",
              "7678"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "_id": {
              "value": "9175-9844-0075-7678"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Or like this:

```
{
  "timeout": "5s",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "rgtnRelt.reltRcptIdI": {
                    "value": "9175",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "rgtnRelt.reltRcptIdI": {
                    "value": "9844",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "rgtnRelt.reltRcptIdI": {
                    "value": "0075",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "rgtnRelt.reltRcptIdI": {
                    "value": "7678",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "_id": {
              "value": "9175-9844-0075-7678"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not getting the desired result

Comment: I have used the below query and it worked for me.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me

```
{
    "query":{
        "bool":{"should":[
            {"match_phrase":{"rgtnRelt.reltRcptIdI":"9175-9844-0075-7678"}},
        {"match":{"_id":"9175-9844-0075-7678"}}]
    }   }
}
```